# Why was Natsu called a pervert?

Tags: fairy-tail

In chapter 421, we see Natsu tickle Lucy's feet. Nothing out of the ordinary, yet he gets called a creep/sicko perv. So is tickling someone's feet considered a pervert act in Japan?

[image]

Comment: I always thought it was because he keeps showing up in her house unannounced and uninvited.

Comment: Step 1) go to japan step 2) look at a girl step 3) Watch them calling you a pervert (or they might just run away) step 4) think step 5) ??? Step 6) profit. (reference, south park)

Comment: @ardaozkal I got to step 2 but nobody said or did anything. I even took pictures. So how do I get to profit? :(

Comment: Send me the pictures :P

Comment: You did the first step wrong, you are in Belgium!

Comment: @ardaozkal Not during summer, mister stalker huehuehue

Comment: D'oh! (lucky you, don't know enough japanese or have enough money to go to japan)

Comment: @ardaozkal Work your ass off and one day you'll be able to go! Hopefully :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lucy calls the guys perverts a lot. It's sort of her thing.

She calls Natsu a pervert in part because there seems to be a running gag of him coming into her personal space unannounced and unwelcome.

It goes along with the running gag of Gray always taking his clothes off... and getting called a pervert.

Answer (score 0):

I thought she was just embarrassed because lately he's asked her to join a bath and blown fire between her legs so maybe she assumed he was trying to start being perverted and stopped him (even though this time I doubt he meant it as a perverted way at all but he HAS *been* a pervert so can you blame her?).